# In FORTRAN, what is the use of FMT without parameters?

Tags: arrays, io, fortran

I check an old FORTRAN 77 program.
It has an FMT character array, lets say:

```
CHARACTER*4 FMT(4)
```

which gets some elements like:

```
/'9,','1X','A','0'/ ...etc...
```

During execution, FMT elements might get different values
e.g.:

```
FMT(4) = '3x'
```

I m confused because the WRITE statement is like this

```
WRITE (xOUT,FMT) 'Result: ',(trek(j),j=1,Nev)
```

The FMT is an array. Right ?  Not a string.
So what FORMAT exactly will the WRITE read from FMT ?
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `FMT` is a character array. When an array is used as the format of an input/output statement, it is treated as though (Fortran 2018, 13.2.2 p3) each element is specified and concatenated. So in this case

```
write(xOUT,FMT) ...
```

is interpreted like

```
write(xOUT,FMT(1)//FMT(2)//FMT(3)//FMT(4)) ...
```

Which is unfortunate, because `FMT(1)` must have a `(` as its first non-blank character.

Outside a character edit descriptor blanks in a format are not significant.

---

This, although it initially seems odd, is a handy way to create dynamic formats.  Consider an extreme example where we want to write a string used as a format which could be `(I5.5)` or `(F26.14)`.

This could be:

```
character(6) fmt(3)
fmt(1) = '('
fmt(3) = ')'

if (something) then
  fmt(2) = 'I5.5'
  print fmt, 113
else
  fmt(2) = 'F26.14'
  print fmt, 123.56
end if
```

(Yes, you wouldn't do this, I hope, but one can easily extend this to situations where it does seem appealing.)

Compare with

```
character(8) fmt
fmt = '(      )'

if (something) then
  fmt(2:7) = 'I5.5'
  print fmt, 113
else
  fmt(2:7) = 'F26.14'
  print fmt, 123.56
end if
```

to see what the author was trying to avoid.

Comment: Ok, so it takes the elements of the FMT array, concatenates them and creates a FORMAT string.
But in this case it sounds absurd because the FMT array has 30 elements...  CHARACTER*4 FMT(30)
Shouldnt it choose (somehow) which elements to include ?
Or i didnt get the "Outside a character edit..." part

Comment: You say `CHARACTER*4 FMT(4)` in the question. For any array it will be all elements (4 or 30), and there's no choice. Any blanks before the first `(` and after the final `)` are ignored, as will most blanks inside the array.

Comment: If you can show a complete example (see [mre]) of the array's manipulation with a valid format, I can add detail of the working.

Comment: The program is more than 1000 lines of code. With several subroutines and several FMT(n) ='something'. I tried to simplify the problem here, in case i would understand it better. Thats why i mentioned 4 elements FMT(4) instead of (30). For example before a specific WRITE instruction it only changes FMT(3) FMT(4) and FMT(6) then it WRITE(xOUT, FMT). I will leave the thread on for a couple of days in case anyone or even me come up with something and if not, i will mark @francescalus answer accepted.